# Problems publishing a DataStudio report in a wordpress Personal Plan website

Tags: wordpress, looker-studio

I have a Personal Plan on wordpress.com. I try to insert a DataStudio report in my web page, with the code shown below.

```html
<iframe width="600" height="338" src="https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/1ASFCkRvzhHmT_kPLlT8npwKlJNS88ezz/page/hRet" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I can see the report working in the editor html preview, but not in the page preview and of course not even if I publish it. I am quite sure the iframe from DataStudio is working as I tested it from JSFiddle.com. I am suspecting wordpress bans publishing iframes? I have tested with shortcode `[embed]` and the same thing happens.

There is no reference to the iframe in the webpage, not even the box...+
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your suspicion; for `wordpress.com` hosted sites, iframes are blocked/disallowed except for on the "Business Plan with Plugins" paid plan. Directly from https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/:

> The following codes are not allowed on sites on our Premium Plan and below for security reasons:
>
> - embed
> - frame
> - **iframe**
> - form
> - input
> - object
> - textarea
> - and more

Your options are to either upgrade to the ["Business" or "eCommerce" plan](https://wordpress.com/pricing/), or move your site off Wordpress.com.

Comment: thaks Joshua for your help!.. I have my webpage just for hobby, likely will look for another solution/host when the contract cones to end...thanks again